# How can I call a non-static method in a child Activity of an ActivityGroup from the ActivityGroup?

Tags: java, android

I think the easiest way to ask the question would be to demonstrate how my current workflow is set up first:

1. There is a `TabHost` that has an `ActivityGroup` as one of its tabs
2. That `ActivityGroup` as an `Activity` in it that calls an external service that I have no control over.
3. The External Service has a callback function that kicks off `onActivityResult` in the `ActivityGroup` and **NOT** in the `Activity` that called the Service.  This is because in order to have even have the `onActivityResult` fire, I had to call `getParent().startActivityForResult(`

The problem is that I want 'stuff' to happen in the `Activity` that called the External Service (e.g. an `Alert Dialog`, a web service call etc).

So, how can a call a non-static method in the child Activity from the `ActivityGroup`? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  In the `ActivityGroup`'s `onActivityResult` I got the current activity using `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()`and **edit:** cast it as the class I need, then called the non-static method on it:

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        FooChildActivity foo = (FooChildActivity)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
        foo.barNonStaticMethod(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 }
```

Comment: A minor point: you are not "converting" the current activity to the class you need; you are "casting" it to the class you need.  It's minor, but not unimportant.  If it were possible to *convert* to a different class, this would work even if the current activity were not of the desired type.  It's not possible, and it wouldn't work in that situation.  The activity in question is _already_ of the desired type, and that's why casting works.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying that! I'll edit my answer to use the correct terminology.